# Charm Down license

Tags: gluon-mobile

I noticed that some time ago the `Charm Down` license was changed to the `GNU General Public License 3`.

Now I wonder if I can use Charm Down in a commercial app, without being bound to that license, i.e. to release the app as closed source.

There is a lot of questions and answers in the net about the topic Gnu GPL3 in commercial products however with widely differing opinions, so maybe somebody of the Gluon staff can provide a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see at the Charm Down [repository](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down), Charm Down is GPL licensed, but commercial support and licenses are also available.

You need a commercial (non-GPL) license if you want to use Charm Down in commercial (non-GPL) software.

If you buy a Gluon Mobile license, you get Charm Down as well under a commercial license.

Or if you don't use Gluon Mobile, you can also get a commercial license for Charm Down, paying a once off fee.